# Generic argument in dynamic proxy interceptor

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy, ninject-interception

To add and retrieve objects from memory cache I have a cache util class with these methods:

```
public static T GetNativeItem<T>(string itemKey)
public static void AddNativeItem(string key, object item, TimeSpan timeout)
```

to remove some noise from data access class I would like to use [**Castle Dynamic Proxy**](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), in this particular case I would use [**Ninject.Extensions.Interception**](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Interception).

The problem is the `GetNativeItem<T>(string itemKey)` of the cache util, in my interceptor how can I retrieve `T` from `invocation`?

The NinjectWebCommon binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IMatchDataAccess>().To<MatchDataAccess>().Intercept().With<CacheInterceptor>();
```

The IMatchDataAccess interface have this signature:

```
public interface IMatchDataAccess
{
    [Cached(minutes: 10)]
    IEnumerable<DomainModel.Match> GetMatches(MatchFilterDto matchFilter);
}
```

and the CacheInterceptor have this implementation:

```
public class CacheInterceptor : IInterceptor
  {
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
      var cachedAttr = invocation.Request.Method.GetAttribute<CachedAttribute>();

      var p = invocation;
      if (cachedAttr == null)
      {
        invocation.Proceed();
        return;
      }

      var cacheKey = String.Concat(invocation.Request.Method.ReturnType.ToString(), ".", invocation.Request.Method.Name, "(", String.Join(", ", invocation.Request.Arguments), ")");

      /*
          problem is here
      */ 
      var p = invocation.Request.Method.ReturnType;
      var objInCache = CacheUtil.GetNativeItem<p>(cacheKey);


      if (objInCache != null)
        invocation.ReturnValue = objInCache;

      else
      {
        invocation.Proceed();
        var timeout = cachedAttr.Minutes > 0 ? new TimeSpan(0, cachedAttr.Minutes, 0) : new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0);
        CacheUtil.AddNativeItem(cacheKey, invocation.ReturnValue, timeout);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tentative [**I found the solution here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method), using Reflection:

```
var method = typeof(CacheUtil).GetMethod("GetNativeItem");
      var gMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(invocation.Request.Method.ReturnType);

      var objInCache = gMethod.Invoke(typeof(CacheUtil), BindingFlags.Static, null, new object[] { cacheKey }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```